# Generate Signed APK Errors

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio

When I run an application in the emulator it works, but when I want to generate a signed APK I get the following error message:

> [Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   0xffff]: 65536]

What does this error message mean and is there a way to solve this issue?

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Eclipse and Android Studio are completely different things, which one are you using?

Comment: try the suggestion and update if there is any problem

Answer (score 1):

`DexIndexOverflowException:` Overflow mean a limit has been reached.

Your `dex` file size has reached it's limit i.e 64K so you need to implement `Multidex` support into your project [follow the official link of docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

or

add below to build.gradle to enable multidex support

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

set the app name multidex support in your manifest application tag

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And if you have an application class then enable dex before `super.onCreate`

```
MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());
super.onCreate(arguments);
```

**Some tricks might handy :** Remove unwanted dependencies ,files and use specific google play dependency like gms etc instead of adding it as a whole plus you can use best practice for proguard rules [follow the link for an example](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices/blob/master/templates/rx-architecture/app/proguard-rules.pro)

Comment: Also, just to add, Progaurd is an option to remove unused code and stay below the 65k method limit

Comment: @Shmuel yeah it useful but max you can remove logs code or some similar thing otherwise progaurd do it's job in very efficient although many time we have to tell progaurd don't shrink this(POJO etc) and that , :P:P so it may or may not be effective depend upon the project but still will add more efficiency

Comment: Progaurd is really useful shrinking 3rd party libraries. I've removed more than 20k lines of code from a project.

Comment: @Shmuel yeah i agree , but i am not really sure which additional proguard rules can be used excepts for log  so i gonna add a link ,thanks  plus if you have any suggestion , feel free to suggest an edit ,:)